# Output to file from pgsql trigger

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

Is it possible to output some text to a file (a fifo actually) from a PostgreSQL trigger written in **plpgsql**?

I know I could create a C trigger for that, I was wondering if it could be done in plpgsql.

Comment: PL/PGSQL has no direct file access.  You could use another language which could do this or you could use COPY if you want to output data.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need to append to the file (i.e. always create a new one) [`COPY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html) might be an option